# how list methods work?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How list methods works in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252068/how-list-methods-works-in-java)

List is an interface in java. And it has some methods. Generally an interface is a specification of method prototypes. i.e. interface consist of methods signature only no implementation will be there for that methods in interface.

I have a doubt that how the methods of List interface work if they don't have any implementation inside the interface.

Suppose I have a class Book which has name property, setter,getter methods. and I have another class getBooks like this.

```
public class GetBooks{
List<Book> list;
public List<Book> getBooks(){
return list;
}
//setter method..
}
```

I am sending books into the set method at runtime through some other class.

I have another class UseBooks like this.

```
public class UseBooks{
.....
....
List<Book> list = new GetBooks().getBooks();
list.add(new Book("aaa"));
}
```

My question is how add method is adding books even it is in interface List because my getBooks() returning List interface not Arraylist or some other implementation class.

Comment: You will always have an implementation of the List-Methods.

Comment: `List<Book> list = new GetBooks().getBooks();` wont compile.

Comment: List is a interface, you will create new object with implementations like ArrayList and ArrayList is a class which extends List interface and it does have complete implementations of interface methods.

Comment: You already asked this, and got answers. You really, really need to either read the tutorials provided by oracle or buy a good beginner's book on Java.

Comment: @Karthik the code (idea) compiles correct, but  will get always NPE.

Comment: @rahul the code is correct because you satisfy the contract (interface) but on runtime you will get a NPE at list.add() because you never instantiate an implemntation of the contract (interface).

Comment: @PeterMmm Do you mean that it works if he removes the `new`?

Comment: @KarthikT i have asked the question bcoz my previous question similar to this was not answered.

Comment: @KarthikT ur down votes made me not authorize to ask any further questions. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Book> list
```

Here list is a reference to an object, not an object itself. When you call interface methods on this reference, you are actually calling the overridden methods of some concrete class that this reference points to.

To illustrate

```
List<Book> list = new List<Book>(); //Illegal
List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>(); //legal ArrayList is a concrete implementation of list.
```

That is the power of interfaces, I can do stuff with this reference without worrying about how it works or how it is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You need to create an object of List of Books like as follow

```
//list as object
List<Book> list = new ArrayList<Book>();

//get your data

List<Book> temp = getBooks();

//now add another List of records to list

list.addAll(temp);
```

Note:= As You said You will get List of Book by getBooks() method, so i explained in Example